# What is the professional way to set couchDB directory programmatically in python

Tags: python, directory, installation, couchdb, config

I'm trying to set up CouchDB in python and I encountered a problem before I even really started coding.

The first thing I have to do is to **programmatically** change the directory of the database. I need the files on a bigger disk and sometimes I might even need to switch disks. Unfortunately this is the only way I could come up with (It uses regular expressions and edits the config file directly):

```
def setDBDir(self, dbdirectory = "/new/database/directory"):
    dbdirectory = dbdirectory.replace("/", "\\/")

    variable = "database_dir"
    print "setting", variable, "=", dbdirectory 
    command = "sudo sed -re 's/^("+variable+")([[:space:]]+)(=)([[:space:]]+)(.*)/\\1\\2\\3\\4"+dbdirectory+"/' -i.'date -I' /etc/couchdb/default.ini"
    os.system(command)
    print command

    variable = "view_index_dir"
    print "setting", variable, "=", dbdirectory 
    command = "sudo sed -re 's/^("+variable+")([[:space:]]+)(=)([[:space:]]+)(.*)/\\1\\2\\3\\4"+dbdirectory+"/' -i.'date -I' /etc/couchdb/default.ini"
    os.system(command)
    print command
```

This code is so ugly and unprofessional, it hurts my eyes and my brain. Even worse, it asks the user for root password on the terminal (I couldn't even use gksu because gksu can't parse the sed command properly with all those spaces and fancy characters behind it).

Is there a better and safer way of doing it?

In other posts I stumbled upon this:
http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/server/configuration.html#put--_config-section-key

Could this be relevant to my problem? I have yet no idea how couchdb works in detail, I just started familiarizing myself with it.

Could someone provide me with a nicer [edit ;)] Pythonic solution? I'm hoping for some set_config() call provided inside couchdb-python or couchdbkit? I previously experimented with redis and they had something like that.

**edit:**

I need those separate databases to manage file corruption cases and for the case that one of the databases becomes too big to fit onto the same drive. I have one main database from which I can reconstruct all others, but such reconstruction is very CPU consuming and would take over one week (that's why I precalculate and store those values separately).

I will backup the main database from time to time, but I can't waste disk space to regularly backup the others. In that way, if I loose others, it will be bad but it won't be end of the world.

In addition my data will be put in directories that reflect the meaning of the data and if I choose to install my application on a different computer with decisively more disk space, I could ship it in a standalone configuration where all databases are somewhere inside of the application directory.

Comment: Python coders prefer the word *Pythonic* :)

Comment: Why are you changing the database directory of the system-wide database? If your program has to have that much control over it, would it not be better to run a separate instance of the database under the same user?

Comment: I didn't really expect that there could be something else than system-wide. I have seen the local.ini, but there was no "database_dir" in it. Are you saying I can run multiple instances in multiple directories? How would I do that in python?

Comment: You can use your own config file and set the data directory, log files, and ports to anything else (hopefully where the user has write access). Try `couchdb -n -a yourconfig.ini`.

Comment: So I would need to write/generate one config per database and then start multiple instances with `os.system(couchdb -n -a myconfigx.ini)` passing location of the ini file and choosing a unique port. I hope it doesn't eat up too much memory / that there are memory limiting parameters I can set. The total data to be served is 50 GB.

Comment: You can do that, although I don't know why you need *multiple* instances of CouchDB / one config per database. It would be nice if you can explain in your question why you need all these separate configurations.

Comment: I updated my question to provide you with the information